# Ruby on Rails - import Bootstrap error "File not found or unreadable"

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sprockets

I am new to RoR and am currently developing in a cloud IDE called Cloud9.  I have developed an app that runs fine, but while updating my css file, out of nowhere when I launch the site I see

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
       on line 1 of .../app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

1: @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
2: @import "bootstrap";
```

This appears in the top-left corner of the HTML page and I'm not sure why since all the CSS is loading properly.  This error randomly appeared and Im not sure how to get rid of it.

### custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #777;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #777;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* forms */

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

.checkbox {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  span {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

#session_remember_me {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding the extension to the application.js file like so:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: This did not work, the error is still there... it's very odd, this problem seemed to show itself randomly, but it is persisting.

Comment: did you include custom.css.scss into your application.css file? `*=require custom`

Comment: Yes, still shows the error.  But this isnt an error I am redirected to.  It shows up on the individual pages of my app.  I added an image to the question

Comment: final thing i can think of is adding `bootstrap` into the application.js file like i have updated above. If that doesn't help, maybe someone else can chime in.